# Nancy response not returning proper MIME Type for index.html including

Tags: javascript, c#, html, nancy

So I'm creating an API with Nancy to allow my index.html to include css and javascript files with a GET request.

The problem I'm currently getting is this:

[image]

The Nancy code i'm using to achieve this is:

```
        Get["/{path*}"] = api => {
            var parentDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.StartupPath);
            var path = String.Concat(parentDir, "\\Ui\\", api.path);
            if(!File.Exists(path)) {
                return new TextResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
            }
            return Response.AsFile((String)api.path, (String)MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(api.path)).Contents;
        };
```

The content-type is correct when I debug but it isn't interpreting it properly. I've seen that it might be an issue with me returning the contents instead of the full response but when I do that I get this error:

```
GET http://localhost:8090/js/controllers.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
```

I've also tried adding static directories in the bootstrapper but I get the same "ERR_CONNECTION_RESET" error.

For a test of sanity, I do get the proper file if I directly call it even if it isn't proper, for example:

[image]

Any help is appreciated!

EDIT: So I added these lines of code and the mime type was fixed, going to do some more tweaking (might be a better way):

```
        var fileContents = Response.AsFile((String)api.path).Contents;
        var response = new Response();
        response.ContentType = (String)MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(api.path);
        response.Contents = fileContents;
        return response;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    var fileContents = Response.AsFile((String)api.path).Contents;
    var response = new Response();
    response.ContentType = (String)MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(api.path);
    response.Contents = fileContents;
    return response;
```

Did the trick, I will use this.